# I'm trying to perform integer division on numbers greater than size of any data type available

Tags: java, android, biginteger

As far big numbers are concerned, i know there is a class available in java BigInteger, but i have a constraint that i can't use this and i have to perform division without using library.

This is what i have tried so far,  but got memory leakage issues and not getting any answer

```
private Integer getDivisionResult(ArrayList<Integer> first, ArrayList<Integer> second) {
    int firstLength = first.size();
    int secondLength = second.size();
    int counter = 0;
    if (firstLength < secondLength) {
        return counter;
    }
    do {
        int carry = 0, cursor1 = firstLength - 1, cursor2 = secondLength - 1;
        for (int i = firstLength - 1; i >= 0; i--, cursor1--, secondLength--) {
            int value = 0, from = 0;
            from = first.get(cursor1) - carry;
            if (from < (cursor2 < 0 ? 0 : second.get(cursor2))) {
                if (cursor1 > 0) {
                    from = 10 + from;
                }
                carry = 1;
            } else {
                carry = 0;
            }
            value = from - (cursor2 < 0 ? 0 : second.get(cursor2));
            first.set(i, value);
        }
        counter++;
    }while (isLesserThan(second,first));
    return counter;
}


private boolean isLesserThan(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> firstList) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (list.size() < firstList.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (firstList.get(i) > list.get(i)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        } else if (firstList.get(i) == list.get(i)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm calling getDivisionResult inside this method, after passing certain error cases:

```
 /**
 * @param numOne
 * @param numTwo
 * @return sign : true (negative) , false (positive)
 */
public Result getResult(String numOne, String numTwo) {
    Result result = new Result();
    int res = 0;
    boolean sign = false;
    ArrayList<Integer> firstNum;
    ArrayList<Integer> secondNum;
    if (isNegative(numOne)) {
        firstNum = getArray(numOne.substring(1));
        if (isNegative(numTwo)) {
            sign = false;
            secondNum = getArray(numTwo.substring(1));
        } else {
            secondNum = getArray(numTwo);
            sign = true;
        }
    } else {
        firstNum = getArray(numOne);
        if (isNegative(numTwo)) {
            sign = true;
            secondNum = getArray(numTwo.substring(1));
        } else {
            secondNum = getArray(numTwo);
        }
    }
    if (isNull(secondNum)) {
        result.setSign("Division by 0 is not permissable");
        result.setValue(res);
        return result;
    } else {
        if (isNull(firstNum)) {
            result.setSign("");
            result.setValue(res);
            return result;
        }
        firstNum = getNumberWithoutZeroes(firstNum);
        secondNum = getNumberWithoutZeroes(secondNum);
        res = getDivisionResult(firstNum, secondNum);
        if (sign) {
            result.setSign("-");
        } else {
            result.setSign("");
        }
        result.setValue(res);
    }
    return result;
}

private ArrayList<Integer> getNumberWithoutZeroes(ArrayList<Integer> num) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer x : num) {
        if (x == 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            list.add(x);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

private boolean isNegative(String num) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (num.startsWith("-")) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean isNull(ArrayList<Integer> num) {
    boolean result = true;
    for (Integer x : num) {
        if (x > 0) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private ArrayList<Integer> getArray(String num) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] arr = num.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(arr[i]));
    }
    return list;
}
```

if someone can help me to give a better solution to my problem, I would be grateful

Comment: "I have a constraint..." So this has got to be some special challenge project for school, and you are essentially trying to cheat. There is NO OTHER REASON I can see for not letting you use the perfect solution that is already built into the JDK

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is almost certainly a challenge in programming class to duplicate functionality already in java

Comment: what i want to know is only is there any better solution exists or not? rest is do whatever you like.

Comment: Questions asking for a better solution are also off-topic on SO, as answers to such questions are nearly always opinion-based

Comment: There are many great online resources that show how to divide multiple digit integers. Try to find the file `divmnu.c` for some help. It uses Knuth's method. http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/divmnu.c.txt. OK it's not Java, but easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the solution to my own problem, but the problem now is its processing speed.